# Android Studio cannot create a new project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 130.687321. Whenever I use an upgraded version of Android Studio NOTHING will load at all so stuck to this.
Been using it for a couple of weeks just for intermediate coding nothing too fancy. 
Now was at an Android training session,made one project then while trying to create the second one this error came up after clicking New Project. Don't necessarily want to go back to ADT bundle so that's not an option.
Any ideas?
 This was there on the Event Log
`12:40:29 PM IllegalArgumentException: Error during dispatching of java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(49,65),absolute(41,57),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on frame0: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/android/tools/idea/wizard/ConfigureAndroidModuleStep$AndroidTargetComboBoxItem. must not be null (show balloon)`

Comment: Have you just tried uninstalling and reinstalling then updating Android Studio?.

Comment: hoss ive done this so many times but a newer version of Android Studio after this version always gives me errors but i will get the latest copy tomorrow and try it. thanx alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on what @hoss said, updating any version prior to ver 0.2.0 requires a full un-unstallation, then re-install the new version found at [the android developer website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). Read specificly **updating to 0.2.x** You will find that many errors will be caused if these directions are not followed. This is because of a change in the build Gradle.